# Возможно ли заменить видео поступающее с веб-камеры, картинкой или видео с компьютера?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Возможно ли заменить видео поступающее с веб-камеры, картинкой или видео с компьютера?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно. Например, у вас есть приложение на Delphi, которое на форме отображает видео поток, используя какой-либо компонент. Чтобы отображать поток из файла, надо подать на вход компонета поток из файла, а чтобы отображать поток с устройства, надо подать на вход поток с устройства.

Для Delphi доступны качественные компоненты по работе со звуком и видео, например, [VideoLab](http://www.mitov.com/products/videolab).